# What are allowed characters for the image names in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, images

I am working on a project that uploads the images via API and we are wondering what are the allowed characters for Image Names in SFMC? It would be great to know what is the allowed length of the image-name, too?

Answer (score 0):

The max length for the name of the image can be 100.
**Cannot contain illegal characters = " < >**

Comment: Thanks Swati! I am looking for some official documentation references if you know them?